# App not shown in Android app list

Tags: installation, side-loading

I am trying to install one app(updated version) but when I install it it says this app can not be installed because same kind of app is already installed but when I check apps on android phone I do not find that app of same name that I want to install as updated version. 
I believe it is blocked by the user of the phone, (phone isn't mine now)

what should I do if the app is in the phone but invisible or blocked , 
how do I see it and uninstall it so that I install updated version on it.

kindly guide me what to do in this situation .

thanks and stay blessed

Comment: The app list on some device do not show all apps. Use an app like [AppInspector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubqsoft.sec01) to see the full list.

Comment: other application has the same package name